# Git deleted my files. Can they be recovered?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I created a git repository on BitBucket to keep track of my scripts. I only have very limited experience with git. I use a combination of Linux and Windows but I have been adding files to the repository using git bash shell on Windows which has a drive mapped to the Linux share.

I have been adding files over the last few days, but on one of my commits I entered the wrong comment. I wanted to fix this and googled for a solution. The suggestion I found was to use rebase. I tried this but it wasn't successful so I decided to just live with the wrong comment.

After this I created two more scripts which I then wanted to add to the repository with 'git add'.

When I tried to commit these I got the message "You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on '3ac74cb'". After this message was a list of files and then another line with suggestions as what to do. Unfortunately all this has now moved out of the terminal buffer so I can't track back what the message were, but I basically followed the messages.

One of the messages also suggested that I do a pull - this was due to the fact that I made changes to a text file which I edited in BitBucket. So I also did a pull.

I have basically done a pull, then a commit again and then a push. None of these seem to have worked so I did some more googling to get rid of the rebase message. Based on the answer I found I did a 'git rebase -abort'.

After this, the two scripts that I was trying to add disappeared.

Can I get my files back from somewhere or are they just deleted? How can I avoid this from happening again because I can't afford to lose work like this. The whole point of using git is to not lose work.

If you need any further information to try and make sense of this mess please just ask. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: As a first step, clone the remote repository (the one on bitbucket) to a new location and get a copy of the content that you already pushed. I believe that the steps you took didn't delete something, but I'll let someone more experience to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you were in the middle of a `rebase` operation when you created your new files in the working directory. Unfortunately using `git rebase --abort` will reset HEAD back to where it was when the `rebase` operation started. If `git status` doesn't show any untracked files then I'm afraid your files may have been lost.

`git rebase` is a very useful command when used correctly but it can also cause a lot of trouble when misused.

For future reference, you can change the commit message for your most recent commit using `git commit -m <message> --amend`. This should prevent you running in to trouble for the same reason in the future.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I have read the documentation on rebase and I am none the wiser. I don't know what its purpose is meant to be. Why would it delete files though? That doesn't sound like a very sensible thing to do, especially without warning. It warns you to death about everything else.

Comment: `rebase` allows you to edit the commit history. Unwanted commits can be removed, commits can be combined and messages changed.

When you aborted the rebase, git did its best to put you back to where you were when you started.

A good habbit to have is to use `git status` before any operation. It'll let you know ahead of time if your merging, rebasing or if any files have changes which you aren't expecting.

I'm sorry you've had a bad experience but I urge you to stick with git, it really is a great tool.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been very helpful :-) I'm grumpy, but I'll give it another go ...

Comment: @jss `rebase` is your best friend for keeping a tidy history. Aside from editing, what I use it most for is keeping a clean linear trunk when merging branches in parallel development instead of having a bunch of jagged merge commits. But, I happily used git for over a year without ever using rebase, so you shouldn't worry about it yet as a beginner. When you're maturely comfortable with the tool, then you can start to use rebase to really polish your work.